# Variáveis com valores absurdos na execução do programa em C

Tags: c, variáveis

Estou fazendo uns exercícios em C e a execução do meu super ultra programa de 5 linhas está com problema. Eu vi várias perguntas por aqui sugerindo que poderia ser um erro não relacionado que estaria corrompendo a variável, mas não consigo perceber o que poderia ser. Isso está acontecendo nos outros exercícios também. Segue o código e a saída:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int numero;

    printf("Digite um número inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero);

    printf("\n O número %d elevado ao quadrado é: %.2f", &numero, pow(numero, 2));
    printf("\n A raiz quadrada de %d é: %.2f", &numero, sqrt(numero));
}
```

---

```
Digite um número inteiro: 4

 O número 6487580 elevado ao quadrado é: 16,00
 A raiz quadrada de 6487580 é: 2,00
--------------------------------
Process exited after 2.115 seconds with return value 0
Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui:

```
 printf("\n O número %d elevado ao quadrado é: %.2f", &numero, pow(numero, 2));
```

você está imprimindo o endereço da variável numero e não o conteúdo da variável numero.

Rode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int numero;

    printf("Digite um número inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero);

    printf("\n O número %d elevado ao quadrado é: %.2f", numero, pow(numero, 2));
    printf("\n A raiz quadrada de %d é: %.2f", numero, sqrt(numero));
}
```

Comment: muito obrigada :D Eu ia ficar até segunda quebrando a cabeça esperando a mediação do curso me responder só por causa desse maldito &.